# Are there any benefits from publishing research on subjects different than one's degree/profession?

Tags: publications, journals, peer-review

Are there any benefits from publishing research on subjects different than one's degree/profession, like being in the healthcare field but publishing about biology or psychology?

Thank you

Comment: The danger is: if you don't know the area, then you will be repeating the mistakes of the past.

Comment: Is your question about whether it is beneficial for someone in a medical field to do basic biological or psychological research? I don't think that is the same as publishing on a different field but that's the way of interpreting your question that makes the most sense to me.

Comment: Sure there are benefits for society if you publish good results in *any* field. But wait, probably you meant some other kind of benefits?

Comment: I once applied for a research job in industry, on forecasting retail sales using time series analysis. I had zero knowledge about forecasting, but a couple of papers where I did inferential statistics in psychology. This was sufficient to convince the company's co-founder (a statistics professor) I'd be able to work my way into the statistics of forecasting. I got the job and still have it ten years later.

Comment: Yeah I meant economical/job benefits to the one publishing. That's inspiring Stephan, I wish I'd get a similar occasion sooner or later.

Answer (score 8):

I have done this, and as I found, there's a few benefits:

- You may be able to introduce a new concept to a field, and see that idea grow.
- It shows a level of flexibility and the power to change. For example, "your field" might not be static. I've given talks in conferences that I never would have thought were my field, and I currently have a *job* in something that's not "my field" - and some of that is due to multidisciplinary papers.